# Strange GCC6 optimization with builtin function

Tags: c, gcc, undefined-behavior, gcc4, gcc6

With GCC6 and the code snippet below, this test

```
if (i > 31 || i < 0) {
```

is **false**, and this printf is executed

```
printf("i > 31 || i < 0 is FALSE, where i=%d", i);
```

and produces this very weird output (GCC6):

> **i > 31** || i < 0 is **FALSE**, where **i=32** /* weird result with GCC6 !!! */

whereas with GCC4 I get:

> **i > 31** || i < 0 is **true**, where **i=32** /* result Ok with GCC4 
>   */

which looks perfectly alright.

**How can this be??**

### Code snippet (broken legacy code!):

```
static int check_params(... input parameters ...) {
    /* Note that value can be 0 (zero) */
    uint32_t value = ....
    int i;

    i = __builtin_ctz(value);
    if (i > 31 || i < 0) {
        printf("i > 31 || i < 0 is true, where i=%d", i);
        /* No 1 found  */
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("i > 31 || i < 0 is FALSE, where i=%d", i);
    }
    return i;
}
```

According to [the documentation about GCC builtin functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html), calling __builtin_ctz(0) must be avoided:

> Built-in Function: int **__builtin_ctz** (unsigned int x) Returns the
>   number of trailing 0-bits in x, starting at the least significant bit
>   position. If x is 0, **the result is undefined**.

So obviously, a solution to the coding error is to simply check the value before calling __builtin_ctz(value). This is clear and understood.

I could just stop there and move to other topics...**but still, I don't understand how I could possibly (with the broken code), get the following output:**

> **i > 31** || i < 0 is **FALSE**, where **i=32** /* weird result with GCC6 !!! */

A weird GCC6 optimization or something?

Just in case it matters at all:

```
Cross-compiler: arm-linux-gcc
Architecture: -march=armv7-a
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: to possibly obtain `i=32`, the test value must have been 0 and per your own question and the documentation, a test value of 0 results in undefined behavior.  With undefined behavior, anything can happen.  Don't expect reliable results when invoking undefined behavior.  Don't even expect repeatable results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Barring undefined behaviour, `__builtin_ctz` will always return a number between 0 and 31 and GCC knows this. Therefore the check `i > 31 || i < 0` will always be false (again barring undefined behaviour) and can be optimized away.

If you look at the generated assembly, you'll see that the condition doesn't appear in the code at all (nor does the then-case).

Comment: Ok, so I need to figure out how to output the assembly code (I'll read the manual) and do it with GCC4 as well as GCC6, to compare the two. Thanks.

Comment: @Bludzee You can output assembly in GCC using the `-S` option. You can also use [the Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/7Q6Rvc) to quickly see the assembly generated by different versions of various compilers online without having them installed.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Undefined behavior doesn't mean "the value will be arbitrary." It means the compiler can do [literally anything it wants to](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). In this case, it looks like the compiler was able to statically verify that *as long as `value` is not 0*, `i` will always be between 0 and 31 inclusive. So it doesn't even bother generating the code for the then-clause.

You're just lucky demons didn't come out of your nose.

See also: [Undefined behavior can result in time travel](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633/), [The premature downcast](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120831-00/?p=6713/), [Why undefined behavior may call a never-called function](https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2017/09/why-undefined-behavior-may-call-never.html), and [many many many other discussions of UB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undefined-behavior) here.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler assumes Undefined Behaviour doesn't happen. It can make that assumption because if the constraints are violated and behaviour is undefined, *any* outcome is possible, including the outcome that would result from the incorrect assumption.

If there is no Undefined Behaviour, then `i` cannot be negative or greater than 31. On that basis, the condition in the `if` statement can be optimised at compile time.

The value actually printed by `printf` cannot be predicted, so it actually calls `printf` with whatever `i` happens to be. In this case, it happened to be 32, but it could have been anything.

Answer (score 0):

The C Standard notes that it is common for implementations to treat Undefined Behavior as an invitation for compilers to behave in a documented fashion characteristic of the environment, and the Rationale notes that classification of behaviors as UB is intended to result in quality implementations providing features beyond those mandated by the Standard when the market demands them.  Nonetheless, judging from their actions, some compiler vendors think that there is more value in having compilers search for clever ways of exploiting the freedom to process certain cases nonsensically than there would be in having them adopt sanely constrained behaviors when practical (e.g. having __builtin_ctz() choose in Unspecified fashion between doing whatever the CPU does or producing some arbitrary value).

I personally rather doubt that the value of any "optimizations" that would be facilitated by allowing compilers to do anything other than either yield a value or perform the CPU operation with whatever natural consequences result would come anywhere close to the value of allowing programmers to assume that on platforms where the CPU itself doesn't do anything weird, the operation will simply yield an Unspecified result with non side-effects.  Nonetheless, the authors of gcc seem to think that requiring programmers to add extra source code to handle accommodate cases which could be handled without extra machine code will somehow improve "efficiency".